# How can i find username/details of people who newly pushed code to github? I am using jenkins pipeline to build and deploy

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have created job in jenkins to trigger a build whenever changes happen in github. But i want to know how to get the details of the user who made the changes to configure email notification.

Could anyone help me with the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git show command to fetch the author ID and email using below command. Assign this to a variable and use it anywhere in the pipeline.

To Fetch Author ID: **git show -s --pretty=%an**
To Fetch Author email: **git show -s --pretty=%ae**

Pipeline script can be written as like below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test Stage') {
            steps {
                checkout changelog: true, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/Sample_branch']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'TestCredentials', url: '']]]
                script {
                     Author_ID=sh(script: "git show -s --pretty=%an", returnStdout: true).trim()
                     Author_Name=sh(script: "git show -s --pretty=%ae", returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
                echo "${Author_ID} and ${Author_Name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned 'TestCredentials'. whose credentials should i use there?

Comment: That is GIT hub credentials. The entire checkout line is dummy one, you need to specify your git hub branch which you need to build and its respective credentials. You can ignore this step if you are using Jenkinsfile for the pipeline.

Comment: Got it. Yes I'm using jenkins for the pipeline. Thanks a lot for the script.